# Creating an Entity Framework object results in a long-running query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database schema that includes tables Orders, Options [Id, OptionGroupId, ...], OrderOptions [Id, OptionId] and an associative table OrderSheetOptions [OrderSheetId, OrderOptionId].

My C# code is creating an OrderOption EF object (an object that maps to the database table):

```
    // Select all default options
    var options = Sheet.OptionGroups.Select(og => og.Option);

    foreach (var option in options)
    {
        // Add all default options
        OrderOptions
            .Add(new OrderOption
                {
                    Option = option
                });
    }
```

The problem seems to arise because I am setting the Option property of OrderOption when it gets created.  This results in EF running this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[OptionId] AS [OptionId]
FROM [dbo].[OrderOptions] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[OptionId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
```

Every Order has a default OrderOption with an OptionId = 1, so as you can see from the above query, every record is returned.  As this table grows, this query is getting very slow and is severely impacting web site UX - delays of minutes.

I am typically only adding 3 records, as those are the default options.  I have added an index to OrderOptions, but it doesn't help because every record in that table has an OptionId = 1, so the automatic EF query returns all records.

It looks like EF is querying the entire OrderOptions table to ensure that a duplicate object is not being created, but the OrderOption is Order-specific, so it only has to worry about the current order.   However, Options is not directly tied to Orders; only indirectly via OrderSheetOptions. So, the EF query can't restrict itself to the current order. Can anyone tell me how I could optimize this so that EF doesn't have to query the entire OrderOptions table just to add a new item?

Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused about your first line of code. What are you trying to accomplish with `Sheet.OptionGroups.Select(og => og.Option);`? I would think your first line should be `var options = Options.ToList()` or `var options = Options.Where(...).ToList();`

Comment: mmilleruva: there is lots more to this database that I'm hoping is irrelevant, so details have been removed.  The options are grouped and assigned to sheets which are part of packages that comprise an order.  So, this line is retrieving the default options for the package that is being ordered.  The point is that I have a list of options that I am adding to the current OrderOptions.

Comment: If you can, you probably want to post the EF model configuration information for Option and OrderOption